# Accessing a Collection in One View From Another (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, code-behind

I am developing a WPF application for displaying data in a plot. I have a `UserControl` that acts as a `View`. In its codebehind file, I have created an `ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>`. These are displayed in the `DataGrid`.

```
    public partial class TagGridView : UserControl
        {
            private TagGridViewModel _tagGridViewModel = new TagGridViewModel();
```

I have another `UserControl`, acting as another `View` that has a `Button` in it. The button opens a file dialog. I would like to be able to use the result of the file dialog operation from the separate view to add an item to the `ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>`, thus updating the grid.

Am I supposed to have a `MainViewModel` in every view containing a static instance of all other `ViewModels` that are required? How can I access the collection?

Comment: No. No. No. No.  Don't create ViewModels for your UserControls.  No.  Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175338/hair-loss-and-mvvm-user-controls/28175766#28175766

Comment: You can pass the collection to the new view when it is getting created and use it there. There are many ways of doing it. As you said Static or Single instance viewmodel is another approach.