# UserControl DataContext Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, datacontext

I have three projects in my solution:

- My main WPF Application which contains a *MainWindow* + *MainViewModel*
- UserControl Library with a UserControl (*ConfigEditorView*)
- UIProcess class with the ViewModel for the UserControl (*ConfigEditorViewModel*)

In my MainWindow I want to use the UserControl with the ViewModel of UIProcess.

First I set the UserControl in my *MainWindow*:

```
<TabItem Header="Editor">
   <Grid>
     <cel:ConfigEditorView DataContext="{Binding ConfEditModel, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
   </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

I don't know which of these properties I need here, so I put all together but it still doesn't work.

Then I've set this in my *MainViewModel*:

```
public ConfigEditorViewModel ConfEditModel { get; set; }
```

With simple method that is bound to a Button:

```
private void doSomething()
{
    ConfEditModel = new ConfigEditorViewModel("Hello World");
}
```

My *ConfigEditorViewModel* looks basically like this:

```
public class ConfigEditorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Description;
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _Description;
        }
        set
        {
            _Description = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ConfigEditorViewModel(string t)
    {
        Description = t;
    }
}
```

The description is bound to a TextBox in my UserControl.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
```

When I start the application and click the Button the TextBox should contain "Hello World" but it's empty.

What I've done wrong?

Comment: Your ConfEditModel doesn't notify the UI of a change so the DataContext of your cel:ConfigEditorView is not updated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175338/hair-loss-and-mvvm-user-controls

Comment: Thanks @nkoniishvt I did not considered that at coding but now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view models (and, optionally, models) need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Binding's aren't magic.  There is no inbuilt mechanism that allows for code to be notified when a plain old property's value changes.  You'd have to poll it in order to check to see if a change happened, which would be very bad, performance-wise.

So bindings will look at the objects they are bound against and see if they implement INotifyPropertyChanged and, if so, will subscribe to the PropertyChanged event.  That way, when you change a property and fire the event, the binding is notified and updates the UI.

Be warned, you must implement the interface and use it correctly.  [This example says it's for 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx), but it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

i gave you a general answer:

within a "real(a usercontrol you wanna use with different viewmodels with different property names)" usercontrol you **bind just to your own DependencyProperties** and you do that with **ElementName or RelativeSource binding** and you should **never set the DataContext within a UserControl**.

```
 <UserControl x:Name="myRealUC" x:class="MyUserControl">
   <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myRealUC, Path=MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc, Path=TwoWay}"/>
 <UserControl>
```

if you do that you can easily use this Usercontrol in any view like:

```
<myControls:MyUserControl MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc="{Binding MyPropertyInMyViewmodel}"/>
```

and for completeness: the Dependency Property

```
    public readonly static DependencyProperty MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUcProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public bool MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUcProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUcProperty, value); }
    }
```